# Crystal Reports - Update SQL in Command without connecting to database

Tags: crystal-reports, report, reporting

I have a problem to update Command in Database Expert. After editing SQL query in Command and click on OK button, Crystal Reports wants to connect into database. But the database is on serves, where I don't have access.

My question is if, there is any possibility, how to update and save edited SQL in Command without connection into database?

[image: Database expert Command Edit]
[image: It always want to connect to database]

I am using Crystal Reports - Product version 10.

Answer (score 0):

No way around this.
But you could create a test/development database with the same structure that you do have access to...

Comment: Thank you, but haven't to be there the same server name too? Unfortunately, I cannot to change server name.

Comment: Use 
Database, Set Data Source Location...
to temporarily point it to a different data source.
If you change to ODBC, things become even simpler, as you can simply point the DSN to another server without changing the report.